# Checking if a message is empty with React Intl and Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-intl

I have an app which uses React Intl and TypeScript.

I want to display a box with some info text, and I want it to be shown *only if* the text actually exists.

But I cannot do

```
<FormattedMessage id="my.id" />
```

because if `my.id` doesn't have a value, React Intl will fallback to the message id, i.e., `my.id`.

So what I tried to do was

```
const myId: string = 'myId';
const info: string = <FormattedMessage id={myId} />;
const infoExists: boolean = myId === info;
```

However, `info` is `JSX.Element`, not `string`.

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
const id: string = 'id';
const componentToBeRenderedIfIdHasValue = ...;

<FormattedMessage id={id}>
    {
        (message: string) =>
            message === id
            ? null
            : componentToBeRenderedIfIdHasValue
    }
</FormattedMessage>
```

I hope this can be of help to someone.

Answer (score 2):

For JS

`const stringExists = !!this.props.intl.messages[id];`

as answered [here](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/747#issuecomment-262318088)